# Initialize and assign value in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component where I am passing input value preferredContactMethods.

I want to initialize another variable alternateContactMethods and assign same value as preferredContactMethods.

I tried:

**Object.assign**

```
@Input()
preferredContactMethods: Array<string>;

alternateContactMethods: Array<string> = Object.assign(this, this.preferredContactMethods);
```

**Direct assign**

```
@Input()
preferredContactMethods: Array<string>;

alternateContactMethods: Array<string> = this.preferredContactMethods;
```

nothing works

Any suggestion or example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides you an [interceptor for input property changes](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter). This will provide you the opportunity to only set the value if your input changes. It will look like this:

```
private _preferredContactMethods: Array<string>;
private _alternateContactMethods: Array<string>;

// Here you can set/compare/calculate/... when your input changes
@Input() set preferredContactMethods(args: Array<string>){
  this._preferredContactMethods = args;
  this._alternateContactMethods = args;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to do following to assign value:

import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input() preferredContactMethods: Array<string>;
   public alternateContactMethods: Array<string>

   ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(this.preferredContactMethods);  // To check value is exist or not.
      this.alternateContactMethods = [...this.preferredContactMethods];. // Assign the copy of preferredContactMethods array
   }

}
```

Comment: This will only work once after your component has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Patent component html file like this:
<Your-Component  [preferredContactMethods]="data" ></Your-Component>

Child Component.ts file   
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input() preferredContactMethods: Array<string>;
   alternateContactMethods: Array<string>

   ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(this.preferredContactMethods);  // To check value is exist or not.
      this.alternateContactMethods = this.preferredContactMethods;
   }

}
```

Comment: This will only work once after your component has been initialized.